# fan is always on high speed and ubuntu hangs on shutdown and restart

Tags: 16.04, nvidia, fan

i have ubuntu 16.04 on asus G551VW with intel i7 and nvidia gtx960m after a certain update (unfortunately i don't remember which package was updated yesterday the) the fan starts at high speed after login by ten seconds and the system hangs on shutdown or reboot with a black screen and one line about cleaning journal

Answer (score 0):

run the following command

```
 top
```

and check which process it is using the high cpu as shown in the following screenshot and kill that process
In general the process might have exceeded the number `100` something like more than `100` means it is the culprit. 
[image]

so note down the process id  `pid` and run `kill -9 pid`

Comment: unfortunately there is no cpu over usage

Answer (score 0):

I have a problem exactly like that, I have Asus N552VX with ubuntu 16.04, After login fan starts on high speed and with a lot noise.
I have searched and it seems the kernel can't find the appropriate driver for fan controller.

it's the output of `sudo sensrs` command

```
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +30.0°C  (crit = +103.0°C)

nouveau-pci-0100
Adapter: PCI adapter
temp1:            N/A  (high = +95.0°C, hyst =  +3.0°C)
                       (crit = +105.0°C, hyst =  +5.0°C)
                       (emerg = +135.0°C, hyst =  +5.0°C)

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Physical id 0:  +34.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 0:         +33.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 1:         +34.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 2:         +29.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 3:         +29.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)

asus-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
cpu_fan:     25500 RPM
temp1:        +30.0°C
```

the cpu speed is 25500 RPM

and this is the  `sudo sensors-detect` summary output

```
Probing for `NXP SE97/SE97B'...                             No
Probing for `NXP SE98'...                                   No
Probing for `Analog Devices ADT7408'...                     No
Probing for `IDT TS3000/TSE2002'...                         No
Probing for `IDT TSE2004'...                                No
Probing for `IDT TS3001'...                                 No
Probing for `Maxim MAX6604'...                              No
Probing for `Microchip MCP9804'...                          No
Probing for `Microchip MCP98242'...                         No
Probing for `Microchip MCP98243'...                         No
Probing for `Microchip MCP98244'...                         No
Probing for `Microchip MCP9843'...                          No
Probing for `ON CAT6095/CAT34TS02'...                       No
Probing for `Atmel AT30TS00'...                             No

Next adapter: DPDDC-B (i2c-16)
Do you want to scan it? (yes/NO/selectively): yes

Next adapter: Synopsys DesignWare I2C adapter (i2c-17)
Do you want to scan it? (YES/no/selectively): YES
Adapter doesn't support all probing functions.
Some addresses won't be probed.


Next adapter: Synopsys DesignWare I2C adapter (i2c-18)
Do you want to scan it? (YES/no/selectively): Adapter doesn't support all probing functions.
Some addresses won't be probed.


Now follows a summary of the probes I have just done.
Just press ENTER to continue: 

Driver `coretemp':
  * Chip `Intel digital thermal sensor' (confidence: 9)

To load everything that is needed, add this to /etc/modules:
#----cut here----
# Chip drivers
coretemp
#----cut here----
If you have some drivers built into your kernel, the list above will
contain too many modules. Skip the appropriate ones!

Do you want to add these lines automatically to /etc/modules? (yes/NO)yes
Successful!

Monitoring programs won't work until the needed modules are
loaded. You may want to run '/etc/init.d/kmod start'
to load them.

Unloading cpuid... OK

reza@reza-N552VX:~$ /etc/init.d/kmod start
[....] Starting kmod (via systemctl): kmod.serviceJob for systemd-modules-load.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status systemd-modules-load.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
 failed!



reza@reza-N552VX:~$ systemctl status systemd-modules-load.service
● systemd-modules-load.service - Load Kernel Modules
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/systemd-modules-load.service; static; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since جمعه 2016-09-09 14:44:06 IRDT; 1min 39s ago
     Docs: man:systemd-modules-load.service(8)
           man:modules-load.d(5)
  Process: 5496 ExecStart=/lib/systemd/systemd-modules-load (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 5496 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

سپتامبر 09 14:44:06 reza-N552VX systemd[1]: Starting Load Kernel Modules...
سپتامبر 09 14:44:06 reza-N552VX systemd[1]: systemd-modules-load.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
سپتامبر 09 14:44:06 reza-N552VX systemd[1]: Failed to start Load Kernel Modules.
سپتامبر 09 14:44:06 reza-N552VX systemd[1]: systemd-modules-load.service: Unit entered failed state.
سپتامبر 09 14:44:06 reza-N552VX systemd[1]: systemd-modules-load.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Comment: solved by upgrading kernel to  4.8RC

Answer (score 0):

attempted solution (all of them failed):
1-updating to kernel 4.6
2-updating to kernel 4.8RC5 (only fixed fan problem)
3-adding`acpi=off` or `nouveau.modeset=0`
4-replacing nouveau drivers by nvidia drivers and the reverse
5-update BIOS
6-run fsck
7-checking the hard disk using live usb

the final solution is:-
reinstalled using live usb which did not complete the boot until i added `nouveau.modeset=0` to the end of linux line in grub (boot the usb highlight the desired option and press `E`) according to byte commander answer to one of the questions after installing ubuntu and booting it up i had to add `nouveau.modeset=0` to grub again to get it to log in probably 
then installed nvidia drivers from settings and rebooted to face the same problem which i fix by chance by reinstalling `ubuntu desktop`>>`sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop`